# Why does date gives me a wrong date?

Tags: php, date

I want to calculate a date based on a timestamp and some other informations.

My function looks like:

```
function getLastDeliveryDate($timestamp,$endOfMonth=true,$extraMonth=0){

    $days               = 0;
    $extraDays          = 0;
    $endOfCurrentMonth  = 0;
    $tsDay              = 86400;

    if($endOfMonth){
        $endOfCurrentMonth = date("t", $timestamp) - date("d",$timestamp);
        //rest of days in current month. In this sample 16 days
    }

    for($i=0;$i<$extraMonth;$i++){
        $x = $i + 1; 
        $date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $timestamp)); //create dateobject to add a month
        $date->modify("+{$x} month"); // add the month (next month)
        $extraDays += date("t", strtotime($date->format("Y-m-d")));
        // get the days of the selected month and add them to count
        // in this case its 31 + 30 + 31 = 92
    }

    $days = $endOfCurrentMonth + $extraDays;
    // count everything together 16 + 92 = 108 days

    return date("d.m.y", $timestamp + ($tsDay*$days));
    //returning date with 108 days added.
}
```

As a sample I call the function like:

```
// the timestamp is 2015-07-15
echo getLastDeliveryDate(1436911200, true, 3); 
// should return 2015-10-31
```

But this return `2015-10-30` and I don't know why. But 108 Days shold be `2015-10-31`. Whats going wrong here ?

If I call

```
echo getLastDeliveryDate(1436911200, true, 2);
```

Its correct and gives me `2015-09-30`

Actually I allways want the last day of the month.

**EDIT:**

Wired, if I test this here: [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ChrZSl) everything works fine. Im my Project it doesn't :(

Comment: Check the timezone offset?

Comment: Even if i have it already in the passed timestamp ? Guess that's not it because the base date is right... and the returned daycounts are also right. So this can't be.. days are all 24h even in timbugtu :D

Comment: do you really set `$endOfMonth` by hand? what is ist for? there is a mechanical and "easy" way of checking whether a timestamp is at the last day of the month...

Comment: $endOfMonth is set manual because its kind of a customer template and sometimes they need the end of the month. This only counts for the beginning date so this just says "yes i want to calc all days of the beginning month" or "no i just want the rest" i know there is some missing... but actually this doesn't matters atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  to create the datetime object before the loop:

```
$date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $timestamp)); //create dateobject to add month
// simpler alternative: $date = new DateTime("@$timestamp");
for($i=0;$i<$extraMonth;$i++){
    $date->modify("+1 month"); // add the month (next month)
    // $extraDays += date("t", strtotime($date->format("Y-m-d")));
    // you can reduce this line to:
    $extraDays += $date->format("t");
}

// Result: 15-10-31
```

otherwise there is always 31 added because you use the day of the timestamp + 1 month.

Note:

You can reduce the whole function to this:

```
function getLastDeliveryDate($timestamp,$endOfMonth=true,$extraMonth=0){
    $date = new DateTime("@$timestamp");
    $date->modify("+$extraMonth month");
    if ($endOfMonth)
        $date->modify("last day of this month");
    return $date->format("d.m.y");
}
```

Comment: No, that's not correct. Its want to create it in the loop to get the days of the selected month from the given timestamp. This is why i have $x in there... BUT, you are right, I could delete $x and call it from outside... actually it just better code :) but, ill give it a try, mom...

Comment: hmm... may im still right... i guess i have a other problem... if i test this somerwhere else... i have the right results :( Anyways thx. Ill vote this up and accept it because its indeed a better code to writh this what I was/am trying to do :)

Comment: Sadly I only can upvote and accept once!!!! Works like a charm. Thank you very much! Edit: with that reduced function i don't have any propblems with the date anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the daylight savings time. You loose one hour on the 25th of october 2015. Since your timestamp is exactly 0:00:00 you lose one hour resulting in "30.10.2015 23:00:00" what should actually be 0:00:00

```
function getLastDeliveryDate($timestamp,$endOfMonth=true,$extraMonth=0){

    $days = 0;
    $extraDays = 0;
    $endOfCurrentMonth = 0;
    $tag = 86400;
    if(date( 'H',$timestamp)==0){$timestamp+=3601;}
    if($endOfMonth){
    $endOfCurrentMonth = date("t", $timestamp) - date("d",$timestamp);
    }

    $date = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $timestamp));
    for($i=0;$i<$extraMonth;$i++){
        $date->modify("+1 month");
        $extraDays += $date->format("t");
    }

    $days = $endOfCurrentMonth + $extraDays;
    return date("d.m.y", $timestamp + ($tag*$days));

}

echo getLastDeliveryDate(1436911200, true, 3);
```

This code has a dirty fix for this problem by adding one hour and one second if your datetime is fixed to 0:00:00. When you don't care about the hours themselves, then this solution will fix your problem and is viable in any case. If you care about the hours, you have to check whether you are in daylight savings time or not and act acordingly.

Comment: That's a very dirty fix :D Ill still give you a +1 because the answere as it is right :) I don't mind about the hours. But yes,by the time I figured out that it was the time. But the solution of Gerald was nice and shinked my source as well :)

Comment: You are right. His solution is way better. Daylight Savings time may mess up things really good....